# EJB stateless beans are not injected properly after migration to JBOSS 7.4 and Java11

Tags: jboss, ejb, java-11, jboss-eap-7

Recently we migrated our application from Jboss 6 to JBoss 7.4 version.
I have a XXXFilter which implements javax.servlet.Filter. XXXFilter uses @Inject annotation to inject some EJB stateless beans. But the problem is the beans are not getting injected into XXXFilter. It's working fine in jboss 6 and jdk8 but NOT working after we migrated to jboss7.4 and jdk11.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the @EJB annotation.

Comment: I tried with @EJB annotation too and it didn't work. But i fixed the issue myself. My dependencies are injected and declared as static. It just worked after removing static keyword. Thanks for your time anyway